# String.indexOf() cannot find System.lineSeparator();

Tags: java, string, newline

I'm trying to find the `System.lineSeparator()` in the `getText()` of a `TextArea`, in FX, but that's a bit unrelated. Anyway, I've got the following batch of code:

```
String newLine = System.lineSeparator();
String log = "Hello there!" + newLine + "I said hello!";
System.out.println(log);
```

The weird thing with the above, is that even though it outputs fine in the console, like so:

```
Hello there!
I said hello!
```

If I do `System.out.println(log.indexOf(newLine);`, I get `-1` printed on the console, that means it didn't find it.

If I do `System.out.println(log.indexOf("\n");` it returns `12`, which is correct (as newLine is the 12th character in the `log`).

Anybody know what's up?

Comment: Looks ok here: http://ideone.com/OkKpqT.

Comment: Can't reproduce: `System.out.println(log.indexOf(newLine));` prints 12 for me (Windows).

Comment: Same for me, it works.

Comment: I've got "\r\n" as System.lineSeparator (Windows) and it's quite OK: 12 is returned

Comment: Damn. That's kind of baffling.

Thank you for the headsup, @OliCharlesworth

Comment: Just a note, I'm on Win7, 64bit, writing a JavaFX app in Netbeans 7.4. May it be a problem of one of these platforms?

Comment: How are you getting the text to serach?  If I recall correctly, using Swing and JTextArea, .getText() converts all line separators to \n regardless of platform.  I don't know if it works the same in TextArea in FX, but that might be a good place to start looking.

Comment: @djmorton, you're a lifesaver. I'm getting it through JavaFX.TextArea.getText(). I'll see if `getTextProperty().get()` yields different results.

Comment: @djmorton Consider posting your comment as an answer so this question does not appear unanswered when browsing questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting above comment as an answer:

If I recall correctly, using Swing and JTextArea, .getText() converts all line separators to \n regardless of platform. I don't know if it works the same in TextArea in FX, but that might be a good place to start looking.